# getting data from hidden textbox in a View using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, input, controller

I am trying to pass data from a hidden input tag text box to the controller

seems that the data is always being passed as null.

My View:

```
<input id="hiddenAwayid" type="text" class="resultAway" name="hiddenAway" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
<input id="hiddenHomeid" type="text" class="resultHome" name="hiddenHome" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult addStatistic(StatisticModel model, string hiddenAway, string hiddenHome)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why are you using text inputs instead of hidden?

Comment: what do you mean ? I always worked with this method dont know the problem here

Comment: Rather than have a textbox that you hide using css (visibility: hidden;), you should just use a hidden input field: <input type="hidden">

Comment: ok and how do I get the data to controler ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the fields into the ViewModel? You can then use:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Awayid)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Homeid)
```

When you post it, the values will be on `model.Awayid` and `model.Homeid`.

The way you did it, I think it's not working because the "id" is different on the html and action.

HTML: hiddenAwayid
Action: hiddenAway

Comment: The html id doesn't affect the submitted POST key name. The name of the field is what is model-bound, and that matches between the form field and controller action. Have to check, but initial guess is that because he's binding a separate model, the simple properties are not getting bound from POST - it's attempting route binding on them. Moving them into StatisticModel will probably fix.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution its pass hidden input with object value like

```
@Html.Hidden("hiddenAway",(value))
```

Or you can make 2 more properties in your Model with that 2 names.